# Sort by minimum value of each group in ascending order of value in SAS

Tags: sorting, sas, grouping, proc-sql

I am trying to sort by the minimum value of each group for the value in ascending order.  I've tried several different combos using of grouping and sorting but haven't been able to sort by group properly. What is the most efficient way?

[image: SAMPLE DATA]

I've tried this:

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE NEED AS 
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM HAVE
GROUP BY ID,VALUE
ORDER BY VALUE;
QUIT;
```

with this output and thought it would sort based on grouping of ID

[image: Sample Output]

Comment: What did you try and what were the issues with the attempt? Please post code and [mcve].

Comment: Ok I posted code and example.

Comment: You want to order the IDs by the minimum value of VALUE for that ID?  If so then you need to have that minimum value on every observation for that ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to sort by the minimum value then it needs to be on every observation.

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE NEED AS 
  SELECT DISTINCT *,min(value) as min_value
  FROM HAVE
  GROUP BY ID
  order by min_value,id,value
;
QUIT;
```

Comment: While this may be an allowed SAS query, it breaks the rules of the SQL standard as `*` is used with  a `GROUP BY`. This query should fail outside of SAS. Possibly, SAS raises warnings. Maybe a future SAS version will support window functions for inline aggregates: `MIN(value) OVER (PARTITION BY ID)`. Also, shouldn't you used `calculated` in `ORDER BY`?

Comment: Sure, in other SQL implementations you might be limited to generating the min via a sub query and remerging it, but the concept of getting an actual variable that you can use to sort by is what is important.

Comment: Yes thank you for this result as it is more elegant than another one I was working on:                                                                                                 
PROC SORT DATA=HAVE;
BY ID VALUE;
RUN;

DATA NEED;
SET HAVE;
COUNT + 1;
BY ID ;
IF FIRST.ID THEN COUNT=1;
RUN;

PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE NEED2 AS 
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM NEED
GROUP BY ID, VALUE, COUNT
ORDER BY MIN_VALUE,ID;
QUIT;

Answer (score 1):

By default, `SQL Procedure` implements automatic remerging of summary statistics.

[Per Documentation](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=sqlproc&docsetTarget=n123fsko39j44pn16zlt087e1m2h.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en#n1kle4xaq72i86n136uqvshf7sfh)

> **Remerging Data**
>
> When you use a summary function in a SELECT clause or a HAVING clause, you might see the following message in the SAS log:
>   **`NOTE: The query requires remerging summary
>        statistics back with the original
>        data.`**
>
> The process of remerging involves two passes through the data.
>
> On the first pass, PROC SQL
>   • calculates and returns the value of summary functions. It then uses the result to calculate the arithmetic expressions in which the summary function participates.
>   • groups data according to the GROUP BY clause.
>
> On the second pass, PROC SQL retrieves any additional columns and rows that it needs to show in the output.
>
> **Note:** To specify that PROC SQL not process queries that use remerging of data, use either the PROC SQL NOREMERGE option or the NOSQLREMERGE system option. If remerging is attempted when the NOMERGE option or the NOSQLREMERGE system option is set, an error is written to the SAS log.

A query that does **NOT** rely on automatic remerging would look like the following example:

```
proc sql;
  create table want as 
  select all.* from
  (select make, min(msrp) as lowest from sashelp.cars group by make) as sequencer
  join 
  sashelp.cars as all on sequencer.make = all.make
  order by sequencer.lowest, all.make, all.msrp
  ;
```

The `LOG` window will show a `NOTE` based on how `lowest` is used:

```
NOTE: The query as specified involves ordering by an item that doesn't appear in its SELECT clause.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try a simple sort:

```
proc sort data = have out = want;
  by descending ID value;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks for your post but this doesn't sort by every ID group based on minimum value.